# Methods of mounting bin/cue pair on OS X?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, mount, bin-cue-image

I have a few bin/cue files, and have tried to convert them to iso using bchunk. That succeeds, but these files have redbook audio, so I'm left with an iso file and associated cdr files, which are basically the raw audio tracks.

I'm trying to install old games into a VM, so while outputting these cdr files gives access to the audio, I don't know how that actually helps me expose the complete data to the vm.

I would like to mount a bin/cue directly if possible, and preferably not rely on DaemonTools lite or similar. Disk Utility will not open a bin or cue file, which was reported as an answer in other questions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [bchunk](http://he.fi/bchunk/), which should be in MacPorts (alternatives are: bin2iso and isodump), to convert that .bin/.cue pair to .iso, and then mount ISO file.

With bchunk, the command (run in console) would be

```
bchunk image.bin image.cue image.iso
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! But as I said in my original question, I tried bchunk. It does output an ISO, but that ISO does not contain the original audio data: it is a "rip" of just the data. bchunk outputs an iso and a series of cdr files, one for each audio track.

Comment: I found this, but never tried.

http://www.crystalidea.com/anytoiso

Answer (score 0):

You can mount disc images (including bin/cue) as a "virtual" disc using [Toast](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/) from Roxio